# Why won't this little Lisp expression work?

Tags: lisp

This is day 1 of Lisp for me. I am trying to eventually write an if else statement...hopefully sometime this year. I am not sure why this is giving me an error?

```
(cond (< 1 2) (print "hey"))
```

Why is this crashing? It says the variable '<' is unbound? I don't get Lisp at all... Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I don't get List at all" - not a good sign.

Comment: "I am trying to eventually write an if else statement." Even in the code that you provided, it doesn't look like you're trying to write an if-(then)-else;  it looks like you're trying to write if-then.  You probably want `(if (< 1 2) (print "hey"))` (which has an implicit `nil` for else, or `(when (< 1 2) (print "hey"))`, which makes it clearer that you don't care about the else part, or `(cond ((< 1 2) (print "hey")))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cond` takes a list of tests and clauses

```
(cond (<test>  <if test is true>)
      (<test2> <if test2 is true>)
      ...)
```

I think what you meant to write is

```
(cond ((< 1 2) (print "hey"))) ;; if 1 is less than 2, print "hey"
```

What you've actually got in your question is

```
(cond (< 1 2)        ;; if `<` is bound as a variable, return 2
      (print "hey")) ;; if `print` is bound as a variable, return "hey"
```

Neither of those symbols are defined in the variable namespace by default, so you'll get an error.

If you only have one form to dispatch on, and only want to do something if it's true, it's more common to use `when` than `cond`.

```
(when (< 1 2) (print "hey"))
```